# How to set backcolor property of the linkbutton set to visible only if it is clicked?

Tags: linkbutton

I have three linkbuttons on my web page. I have provided backcolor of the linkbutton, but I want it to be visible only if that particular linkbutton is clicked. Please suggest how can I do this?
My code is like this-

```
protected void Link_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LinkButton lbtn = (LinkButton)sender;
        lbtn.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
        string id = lbtn.ID;
        if (id == "lnkcot")
        {
           ###
        }
        else if (id == "lnktex")
        {
            ###
        }
        else if (id == "lnkgar")
        {
            ###
        }
    }
```

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it how to do this. . .!
Just set other two link button backcolor equal to transparent. Check below.

```
protected void Link_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                LinkButton lbtn = (LinkButton)sender;
                lbtn.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;

                string id = lbtn.ID;
                if (id == "lnkcot")
                {
                    // set other two to transparent
                    lnktex.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
                    lnkgar.BackColor = Color.Transparent; 
                }
                else if (id == "lnktex")
                {
                    lnkcot.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
                    lnkgar.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
                }
                else if (id == "lnkgar")
                {
                    lnkcot.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
                    lnktex.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
                }
            }
```